# Multiple method calling

Tags: ruby, methods

This just returns the original `name`.

```
name = "George"
name.reverse.upcase!
puts(name)
```

I'm wondering why and if there is any way to do what I tried above.

Comment: yes you can do that. in ruby everything is an object. name is an String Object and the first call you do is `name.reverse`. this return an `String` Object as well. This Object also understand the method `upcase` and so on.

Comment: What is what you tried to do?

Comment: It doesn't return the original name. It returns `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

[`reverse`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-reverse) returns a new string. [`upcase!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-upcase-21) upcases the string it is called on in-place. You are creating a new reversed string, upcasing that new string, and then never using it again.

If you wanted to reverse and upcase the original string you could `name.reverse!.upcase!`

Comment: ..and if you didn't want to mutate (alter) `name`: `revup = name.reverse.upcase #=> "EGROEG"`.

Answer (score 2):

The methods you are calling do not affect the calling object. name.reverse will return a new String and leave the original alone. What you want to do is reassign name after your call.

```
name = George
name = name.reverse.upcase
```

There is a gotcha here in that bang methods, ending in ! will often modify the object being operated upon. So you could do something like below:

```
name = George
name.reverse!.upcase!
```

In general, I would avoid the ! methods unless you have a good reason. The first example of setting "name = " is very clear, easy to read and unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help explain what's happening:

```
name = "George"  # => "George"
name.object_id   # => 70228500576040
```

`object_id` is the memory reference for the actual variable, in other words, where it lives as the script is running.

```
reversed_name = name.reverse  # => "egroeG"
reversed_name.object_id       # => 70228500574980
```

We can tell that `reverse` created a new variable because the `object_id` is different from that of `name`.

```
upcased_reversed_name = reversed_name.upcase!  # => "EGROEG"
upcased_reversed_name.object_id                # => 70228500574980
```

The `upcase!` method modified the same variable as `reversed_name`.

If we use `upcase` instead, the `object_id` changes because a new version of the variable is created:

```
upcased_reversed_name = reversed_name.upcase  # => "EGROEG"
upcased_reversed_name.object_id               # => 70228500572960
upcased_reversed_name # => "EGROEG"
```

The short lesson is you can't assign a `!` method result to a variable because it acts on the original variable and changes it in place.